# Upload a file from react-native (expo) project to a php server (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, react-native, expo, imagepicker

i'v been looking for a solution for this issue for a week now, tried a lot of stuff nothing worked for me, I'm working on a project with react-native built on expo, what i'm trying to do is uploading an image using Imagepicker, i tried submitting it using axios and fetch, i'm able to send text data like (username, email ...) but can't send a file to the server, it doesn't recognise it a all, all it gives me is [object object], if any body was successful on doing that with php please share piece of your code, I did tried the backend with an html form and the file uploaded with no issues.

## Solution

```
let picker = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({ base64: true });

const picker = selectedImage.base64;
```

This will return a base64 encoded image data, all you have to do is send it as a text field to the php server, decode it and put it into a file like this:

```
file_put_contents("example.jpg", base64_decode($_POST['image']));
```

And yeah, it's working

Comment: share a snack or your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simplest solutions is to use the base64 image format.

You can set in the options bese64 to true:

```
    let picker = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({ base64:true });
```

And append the value in a classic json object and avoid the multipar/fomr-data, just for php decode the base64 image.

Answer (score 0):

## React native

// State variable to hold the picked image

```
const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(false);
```

// Use image picker to choose a picture

```
let openImage = async () => {

    let permission = await ImagePicker.requestCameraRollPermissionsAsync();

    if (permission.granted == false) {
      return;
    }

    let picker = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync();

    setSelectedImage(picker);
  }
```

// Upload image to the server

```
    const uploadimage = async () => {
        const payload = new FormData();
        payload.append('image', {
          uri: selectedImage.uri,
          type: selectedImage.type,
          name: selectedImage.fileName
        })
    
        const config = {
          body: payload,
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
          }
        };
    
        let response = await fetch('http://192.168.1.6/php_upload/upload.php', config);
        console.log(response);
      }
```

// PHP Backend

```
$target_file = "uploads/" . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);

if ( move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], $target_file) )
{
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["photo"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
}
else
{
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
```